# I'm trying to learn how to pass pointers in c++, but I get error: no matching function for call to 'test'. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(double &r)
{
    r = 0.1;
}

int main() {
    double rdefined;
    double yo = test(&rdefined);
    cout << yo <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried putting the test function after the main function and assigning rdefined as 0.0 .

Comment: `test` doesn't take a pointer (it takes a reference), but you're passing a pointer.

Comment: You should probably read [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function declaration `void test(double &r)` specifies that the argument is passed **by reference** *not* as a pointer. To pass a "pointer-to-double" use: `void test(double *r)`.

Although, in practice, the effect is very similar, when passing an argument by reference, you don't *explicitly* give the address; so, in *your* code, the call should be as shown below. Also, as noted in the [answer given by Vettri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59530121/10871073), your function does not return a `double` value (or, indeed, anything, as it is `void`), so you can't assign the variable `yo` directly from the call to it.

Try this, as one possible solution:

```cpp
test(rdefined); // Changes the value of "rdefined"
double yo = rdefined; // Assigns modified value to "yo"
```

For a discussion on the differences between pointers and references, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 1):

Corrected Solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double test(double* r)
{
    *r = 0.1;
    return *r;
}

int main() {
    double rdefined;
    double yo = test(&rdefined);
    cout << yo <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You need to specify the correct return value. You got an error because you are expecting a double value in return of your test function, but you declared it as `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is, to replace & with * in the function parameters. here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test(double* r)
{
    *r = 0.1;
}

int main() {
    double rdefined;
    test(&rdefined);
    cout << rdefined <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```